# Excel 2013 64bit Select Date - Update

Tags: vba, excel, activex

Has anyone heard of any update from Microsoft regarding the ability to add a datepicker (click on a cell and select a date from a calendar) to Excel 2013 64-bit?  I know of the common controls but as far as I know, those do not seem to be compatible.

I searched the forums but could not find a recent post so I wanted to see if there was an update from those.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a embedded object which can be linked to a cell under:

developer tab>Insert>More Controls>Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control.

[link](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/insert-calendar-clicking-cell-excel-29766.html)

Comment: Do you know of a link where I can download those tools?
I get this error when going to the download site:
You don't have permission to access "http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/MSCOMCT2.cab" on this server.
http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/mscomct2.cab

Comment: I didn't download anything so I guess it came pre-installed.  Just need to add the developer tab which I believe is outlined on the website.